# Java POSTing File Results In HTTP 422

Tags: java, http, file, post

I'm trying to build a small Java app for connecting to an application called CampFire and am running into trouble trying to upload files to the system.  The Java code I'm using to upload a file is as follows:

```
public static String postFile(String requestUri, File f)
{
  debug("Running postFile.");
  logIn();

  debug("Sending File: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + " to " + campFireURL + requestUri);

  URL url;
  URLConnection conn;

  String linebreak = "\r\n";
  String boundary = "**********xxx**********";
  String twoHyphens = "--";


  String result = "";
  String request = twoHyphens + boundary + linebreak +
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"" + f.getName() + "\"" + linebreak +
    linebreak +
    "";
  debug("Request: " + request);

  try
  {
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

   auth.resetTries();
   Authenticator.setDefault(auth);

   // Send data
   url = new URL(campFireURL + requestUri);
   conn = url.openConnection();
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   conn.setDoInput(true);
   conn.setUseCaches(false);

   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

   DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

   wr.writeBytes(request);

   int i;
   while((i = in.read()) != -1)
   {
    wr.write(i);
   }

   wr.writeBytes(linebreak + twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + linebreak);
   wr.flush();

   wr.close();
   in.close();

   result = readFromConnection(conn);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   debug(e);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error running postData: " + e.getMessage(), "HTTP POST Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   die();
  }

  return(result);
 }
```

When I run this with a real file though, I get the following errors...

```
Running postFile.
Sending File: /home/myuser/Desktop/blah.png to https://blah.campfirenow.com/room/blah/uploads.xml
Request: --**********xxx**********
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="blah.png"
Server returned HTTP response code: 422 for URL: blah blah
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 422 for URL: blah blah
```

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong here?  I'm fairly new at Java and am wondering if maybe I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTTP error 422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) means "Unprocessable Entity". After a quick glance I can spot one mistake: a PNG file is a binary file. You've to add [`Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1521/5.htm) to the header of the part.

If it still doesn't work, then you may find the example in the *Uploading files* section at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  that particular solution didn't seem to help.  You're right though about the binary encoding.  I am still unsure how well the two will mix because I'm sending what seems to be bytes of text content followed by a binary file of some sort. (could be anything really)

Comment: That's covered by the linked example as well.

Comment: Great.  Well, I'm making progress.  Now getting a 500 error instead of a 422.  Thanks for your help though.  I think I'm headed in the right direction.

Comment: Read the `getErrorStream()` to obtain possible error details.

Comment: Which object would have that method?  I'm still stuck getting a 500 error.

Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://xxxxx.campfirenow.com/room/12345/uploads.json
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://xxxxx.campfirenow.com/room/12345/uploads.json

Comment: that is after running: InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

Comment: Cast `URLConnection` to [`HttpURLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). For more hints, see also [How to use `URLConnection` to fire and handle HTTP requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: Unfortunately, that really didn't tell me any more than before.  Just that it was getting a 500 error.  Is there something I'm missing with the HTTPS piece?  I've attempted using HttpsURLConnection but it seemed to make no difference.  The strange part is, I set up a test php script on another server to receive uploaded files, and the Java prog works just fine, uploading to that one.  The only thing I can think that is different is it's not https.